# How many crypto currencies support in bitpay?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, bitcoin

I am using following coins lite coin, doge coin, aurora coin, world coin, max coin, prime coin, peer coin and feather coin. In those coins are supported in bit pay online payment gateway.

Answer (score 1):

No, Bitpay does not support altcoins. I dont think that they ever will! (http://www.reddit.com/r/litecoin/comments/1rq4pf/bitpay_will_not_support_litecoin_and_other/)